# Repopulate ArrayList from JSP with Struts 2

Tags: java, list, jsp, struts2, ognl

This is the form I am using to repopulate the `ArrayList`

```
<form method = "POST" action = "addItemsToTemplate">
    <s:iterator value = "myQuestions" var = "quizItem"  status="key">
        <s:textfield name = "quizItem.question"/> 
    </s:iterator>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
```

This is the action class

```
public class QuizTest extends ActionSupport{



    public String execute(){

            List<Question>  q=  myQuestions;
            System.out.println(myQuestions);

            return "success";
        }


   public String populateQuestions(){
             //more code here
   }

    public void setMyQuestions(List<Question> myQuestions) {
        this.myQuestions = myQuestions;
    }
    private List<Question> myQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

}
```

Where `myQuestions` is a List of Question Objects. upon submission this gives me an error

```
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'quizItem.question' on 'class quiz.actions.QuizTemplateAction: Error setting expression 'quizItem.question' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b3409f'
```

and `System.out.println(myQuestions);` prints an empty list. but the `myQuestions` was already been populated from another by this method    `populateQuestions()`, before submitting the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unexpected Exception caught setting 'quizItem.question' on 'class
>   quiz.actions.QuizTemplateAction: Error setting expression
>   'quizItem.question' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b3409f'

You are trying to send all the questions (attribute) descriptions into the first Question (object) as a `List<String>`, because you are not specifying the index (as you correctly do with `<s:property/>` in your other questions... ?!).

Change this

```
<s:textfield name = "quizItem.question"/>
```

To this

```
<s:textfield name = "quizItem[%{#key.index}].question"/>
```

To send a single `String` to each correspondent `Question` object, instead of a `List<String>` to the first `Question` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Where myQuestions is a List of Question Objects. 
    upon submission this gives me an error
```

Since it is a list of Questions Objects you are trying to populate a Question Object with a String. Please check if you have the converter defined to covert String into Question and also specified in the xwork-conversion.properties file

```
System.out.println(myQuestions); prints an empty list.
```

instead of doing this

```
private List<Question> myQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

do this

```
private List<Question> myQuestions;
```

When you are submiting the form, a new object of your Action class is created and your instance variable "myQuestions" gets reinitialized with each submission.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Btw Question is an abstract class

Comment: BUt  when I do this  private List<Question> myQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>(); it gives me a null value

Comment: if u need the populated value from JSP you need to simply put List<Question> myQuestions; 
Now please check if the JSP flow is going inside the iterator tag by printing a dummy value inside it. 
if you are using eclipe then ctrl+shift+R will open a window where yuo can type xwork-conversion and it will show you the path. If not present in the resources folder of your web module, then you need to add an xwork file.

Comment: I added dummy values and there's actually a content it.  I don't have any xwork-conversion though

Comment: add it and then make a converter for the corresponding Object of Question subclass and add its entry in the xwork.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form Struts2 uses parameters named the same as field names. These parameters are populated to the action by the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) which sets the values to the `valueStack`. Since the action is on top of the stack its properties will be set.

In your action you have an `List<Question>` but passing `List<String>`.

> **[Built in Type Conversion Support:](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#built-in-type-conversion-support)**
>
> collections - if not object type can be determined, it is assumed to be a `String` and a new `ArrayList` is created

To fix the problem use indexed property names like this

```
<s:textfield name = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].question"/>
```

---