# How to set the name parameter on a multiple s:select

Tags: struts2

Imagine you have the following scenario:

- a property in your action: `private Entity entity;`
- Entity has a `List<Entity2> entity2List`
- Entity2 has a `Entity3 entity3`

Now, you need an `<s:select>` with multiple="true" to populate entity3. This corresponds to  having a request in the form `entity.entity2List[n].entity3.id` (n=0,1,2...depending on how many items are selected).

**Question: In the JSP, what should the "name" parameter of the s:select be to achieve this?**

I have tried the following without success (meaning entity.entity2List has is empty):

```
<s:select multiple="true" name="%{entity.entity2List[].entity3.id}" list="#someList" listKey="id" listValue="code"/>
<s:select multiple="true" name="entity.entity2List[].entity3.id" list="#someList" listKey="id" listValue="code"/>
```

Comment: I think you should implement custom struts type converter. Name attribute should be written as entity.entity2List. Implement the converter to convert the value to entity2 type object (which in-turn contains entity3). Set the value to id field of entity3

Comment: Use the indexed properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650800/repopulate-an-arraylist-from-jsp-with-struts2/15657572#15657572